# Почему на моем компьютере приложение node.js выдает пустую страницу

Tags: javascript, node.js, веб-программирование

Есть приложение node.js,  работает оно корректно - На соседних машинах. На моей машине приложение запускается коректно, в терминале и консоли ошибок нет, более того в терминале пишет отклики на запросы. В браузере же - пустая страница. (Не "страница не найдена", а именно пустая страница).

Единственное отличие моей системы - у меня стоит ms sql сервер, возможно он как то мешает. Как новичек в веб я вообще не понимаю что происходит и какие могут быть причины такого поведения приложения.
Запускается и работает корректно в терминале, но не браузере (браузеры тоже разные пробовались). На соседних компьютерах такой проблемы с этим приложением нет.

В какую сторону мне хотя бы искать? Что я могу сделать для прояснения проблемы?

Comment: без кода приложения помочь не сможем

Comment: М@ThisMan Так это не маленькое приложение, там не меньше 50 файлов. На мне была серверная часть, она отлажена и работает в терминале. У остальных работает и в браузере. Но я тоже хочу увидеть интерфейс

Comment: На каком порту запускаете сервер?

Comment: Минимально воспроизводимый код я тоже не могу привести, потому что не воспроизводится эта проблема на других машинах.

Comment: @Suvitruf 8080 , интерфейс и сервер разделены только логически. На разные сервисы они не разделены потому порт один и тот же. если бы порт был занят, оно бы и не запускалось. Заголовок страницы приходит и в браузере виден, так же как и иконка. А самой страницы нет.

Comment: Локальные комманды из консоли curl'ом работают нормально?

Comment: @Suvitruf из консоли всмысле из браузерной? Потому что терминал работает корректно (ubuntu 16) может чем то вроде netstat я могу локализовать проблему

Comment: @Mira а запускаете вы как? Из IDE? Или из терминала?

Comment: Ну чекните на всякий случай. Что выдаёт `netstat -lntu | grep :8080`?

Comment: @Suvitruf запускю из терминала, при помощи yarn. В Yarn start  прописан скрипт babel-node index.js. Для диагностики попробую запустить какое нибудь другое минимальное приложение node.js

Comment: а модули все стоят?  когда себе скопировал про  npm install'' не забыл?

Comment: А какой-нибудь прокси-сервер, не мешает?

Comment: @Air - не помню чтоб npm install делала,  Только yarn (который ставит зависимости подписанные в package.json). Попробую ваш вариант,  Видимо в этом и правда все дело.

Comment: Прости не заметил, что ты девочка...  Команда запуска не устанавливает пакеты....

Comment: @Air вот что значит большой опыт в программировании но не в веб.  Ориентируясь на терминал весь сервер написала, не заметив что модули веб и не стоят.  Оформить пожалуйста ваш комментарий как ответ,  отмечу правильным.

Comment: Благодарю, Mira, но не думаю, что пара строк достойны принятого ответа... Тем более, что мой коммент нет от профессионализма, а от горького опыта)))) Сам так разок сутки мучился и не мог понять, что к чему)))  Рад был помочь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для работы приложения не хватало команд
`npm install`
`webpack`